# Hide headers in multiple ng-repeat if no values during filtering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm struggling with angularjs! Here's the problem. I've a list of employees from different company to show. Data are like these:

```
[
  {
    name : "company1",
    employees : [
        { name : "emp1"},
        {...}
    ]
  },
  { .. }
]
```

I show them using two ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies ">
    <div class="header">{{company.name}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="employee in company.employees | filter:search">
         {{employee.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here we are, I want to avoid, *during filtering* the headers of company with no employees.

Hope you guys are smarter than me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies ">
<div class="header" ng-show="results.length>0"> {{company.name}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="employee in company.employees | filter:search as results">
     {{employee.name}}
</div>
```

**Explaination:** after filtering your filtered data will be stored in **ressults** , which we can use to decide whether to show company name or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I also attached demo.

```
 ng-show="(company.employees | filter:search).length"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('myctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.companies = [{
    name: "company1",
    employees: [{
      name: "emp1"
    }, {
      name: "poiuy"
    }, {
      name: "asdf"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "company2",
    employees: [{
      name: "ghj"
    }, {
      name: "jkl"
    }, {
      name: "ooo"
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl as ct">
    <input ng-model="ct.search">
    <div ng-repeat="company in ct.companies ">
      <div class="header" ng-show="(company.employees | filter:ct.search).length">{{company.name}}</div>
      <div ng-repeat="employee in company.employees | filter:ct.search">
        {{employee.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```